# "wget -N" with Dropbox link always downloads (even if file has not changed)

Tags: python, timestamp, dropbox, wget, dropbox-api

In theory, wget -N should check if the local copy of the file is newer than that on the server, and in this case it should not repeat the download. I'm finding that for a Dropbox link this doesn't happen. The file is always downloaded.

For example, try to do multiple times

```
wget -N https://www.dropbox.com/s/pilu0oufcvrz452/ciaociao
```

and you'll see that, despite the `-N` switch, the file keeps being downloaded.
Do you know why is that? Is there a way to test if the file is older on the server before downloading it? 
Simple shell scripting or python would be better, if possible. I'm using this command in a Python installation script (through a `os.system` call) to download supplementary data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** Note: *Any* solution to the problem would be appreciated. Is there a way to do that using the Dropbox API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this, I see this message in the `wget` output:

> Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.

So, it seems these Dropbox links just don't return the header necessary for this time-stamping option on `wget`.